# What length arrow for "converges to"?

Tags: arrows

To denote convergence of a sequence towards a limit, the usual `\rightarrow` seems too short to me. My document uses Michael Barr's `diagxy` package, which defines `\to`, and that arrow is too long.

How might I get a more suitable length arrow for this?

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\tendsto}{\mathrel{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\usepackage{diagxy}     %% redefines \to

\linespread{1.21}

\begin{document}

Let $(x_{n})_{n \in \N} \tendsto x$ in $X$. %% too short?

Let $(x_{n})_{n \in \N} \to x$ in $X$.      %% too long!

\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows - amsfonts]

The problem is more pronounced with the actual fonts I'm using, namely, Lucida Bright (`\usepackage{lucidabr}` instead of `\usepackage{amsfonts}`):

[image: Arrows - Lucida Bright fonts]

The longer arrow `\to` from Barr's package (which is a nice length for function notation, as in `$f \colon A \to B$`) is defined in this part of `diagxy`:

```
\def\setwdth#1#2{\setbox0\hbox{$\labelstyle#1$}\wdth=\wd0%
\setbox0\hbox{$\labelstyle#2$}\ifnum\wdth<\wd0 \wdth=\wd0 \fi}%

\def\topppp/#1/<#2>^#3_#4{\:%
\ifnum#2=0%
   \setwdth{#3}{#4}\deltax=\wdth \divide \deltax by \ul%
   \advance \deltax by \defaultmargin  \ratchet{\deltax}{100}%
\else \deltax #2%
\fi%
\xy\ar@{#1}^{#3}_{#4}(\deltax,0) \endxy%
\:}%

\def\toppp/#1/<#2>^#3{\ifnextchar_{\topppp/#1/<#2>^{#3}}{\topppp/#1/<#2>^{#3}_{}}}%
\def\topp/#1/<#2>{\ifnextchar^{\toppp/#1/<#2>}{\toppp/#1/<#2>^{}}}%
\def\toop/#1/{\ifnextchar<{\topp/#1/}{\topp/#1/<0>}}%
\def\to{\ifnextchar/{\toop}{\toop/>/}}%
```

Is there some suitable way to exploit code from `diagxy`, or by other means, produce an arrow that's a bit longer than `\rightarrow` but not as long as Barr's `\to`?

Comment: I don't know this package, but why not saving the old definition before loading this package if this is the length you are looking for? `\let\oldto\to \usepackage{diagxy}`

Comment: Or you could use `\xrightarrow` from `amsmath`: `\xrightarrow{\hspace{10pt}}` adjust this space to your needs. Of course you can create a new macro with your desired length: `\newcommand{\myrightarrow}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{10pt}}}`

Comment: I see overlong arrows all the time; keep it as short as possible.

Comment: In part, by making the arrows a bit longer I'm trying to compensate for the relatively small arrowhead size with the Lucida Bright arrows.

Answer (score 2):

I’d like to direct your attention to [`lucida-amsmath.pdf`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/lucidabr). On Page 22, we find that the “normal usage” of the “converges to” symbol is just `\rightarrow` in Equations (48) and (49).

The length of the `\rightarrow` is chose by the font designer. If the designer doesn’t find the arrow head “too small” or the arrow bar “too short”, then we shouldn’t either (and if you disagree, perhaps change the font). But if you insist on designing your own arrow, which you called `\tendsto`, then you can borrow the definition found in [`lucidabr.dtx`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/lucidabr):

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\relbar@}{\mathord}{arrows}{45}
\def\relbar{\mathrel{\smash\relbar@}\mathrel{\mkern-2.5mu}}
% ...
\def\longrightarrow{\mathrel{\mkern4mu}\relbar\rightarrow}
```

We see that `\longrightarrow` is built by simply connecting a `\relbar` with a `\rightarrow`, and then using `\mathrel{\mkern4mu}` to adjust the spacing around this relation symbol.

So, in order to design an arrow of our own use, we could add the following to the preamble:

```
% Adjust the `-2' in \mkern-2mu to suit your need
\newcommand*{\tendsto}{\mathrel{\mkern4mu}\relbar\mkern-2mu\rightarrow}
```

Since I don’t have the Lucida fonts, I can only provide an empirical `-2mu` in the above definition. Adjust this length to suit your need. It is worth pointing out that *there is no standard for how long an arrow should be*, so the length you decide to put into this customized `\tendsto` is totally subjective. **Added**: For Computer Modern, you may find `-8mu` looks good (`\longrightarrow` uses `\joinrel`, which is essentially `\mkern-3mu`).

**Added**: This approach may be better than `\newcommand{\myrightarrow}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{10pt}}}` suggested by @nox, because:

1. This doesn’t require `amsmath`, although it’s very likely that you’ll need `amsmath` anyway if you have a lot of math.
2. This scales correctly in the script- and second-script-levels, since it doesn’t rely on the absolute length like `10pt`. You could use something like `0.8em`, but the arrow head won’t be scaled correctly (Well, you’re not supposed to use `\xrightarrow{...}` in scripts anyway. It was designed to have text placed over/under it).

Both approaches use redesigned arrows essentially.

**Side note**: I don’t recommend using the redefined `\to` from the `diagxy` package: The arrow head simply doesn’t blend with either Computer Modern or Lucida Bright.

### Illustration using Computer Modern

Here is an illustration using Computer Modern:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Many font packages, including lucidabr, redefine things set up by amsmath
% So amsmath must come before math font settings
% See Section 1 of lucida-amsmath.pdf
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\myrightarrow}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{10pt}}}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\tendsto}{\relbar\mkern-8mu\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

%\usepackage{diagxy}     %% redefines \to

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \makebox[7em][r]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}:
  Let $(x_n)_{n \in \N} \csname#1\endcsname x$ in~$X$;
  that is, \[\lim_{n \csname#1\endcsname \infty} x_n = x.\]}

\begin{document}
\noindent\test{to}
\test{tendsto}
\test{myrightarrow}
\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison]

Comment: Why might that arrow re-design be better than using `\newcommand{\myrightarrow}{\xrightarrow{\hspace{10pt}}}`?

Comment: @murray Please check my updated answers. Actually, `\xrightarrow` redesigns arrow as well. However, `\xrightarrow` is meant to be used in `\displaystyle`, so there will be problems in sub- and superscripts.