# Use tikz to create better \to and \mapsto that also match tikz-cd diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I want to use Ti*k*Z to create new versions of the standard LaTeX math symbol `\to` and macro `\mapsto` to use for math mapping notation and, in the case of `\to`, to use for math convergence notation.

And I want the arrow tip style and shaft thickness to harmonize with arrows used in `tikzcd` diagrams.

For the Lucida Bright math font I'm using, I find the arrow tips too small on both — because the arrow tip on `\rightarrow` is so small  — and the bar on `\mapsto` is also too small.

**Questions:**

1. How do I make the terminal `Stealth` arrow tip larger for `\newmapsto`, so that it is the same size as the terminal `Stealth` arrow tip for `\newto`?
2. Does the result of the code shown below create a pleasing and harmonious design of these symbols? Any suggestions for improving either the result or the code?em

**Caution:** Although the code shows the `lucidabr` package, I'm actually instead using the proprietary `lucimatx` package, with its `lucidasmallscale` option that enables "nonlinear" scaling, with 10pt font sizes scaled by 90%, with < 10pt sizes scaled upwards (up to 0.95% at < 5pt) and with > 10pt sizes scaled downwards (down to 0.85 pt at >= 22.5pt). (This is to compensate for the relatively large x-height of the Lucida fonts.)  *The image from the pdf output that's shown below uses* `\lucimatx` *with that scaling.*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=0.75in]{geometry}

%% FOLLOWING LINE USED TO PRODUCE IMAGE SHOWN FOR THE OUTPUT
%\usepackage[lucidasmallscale=true]{lucimatx}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\linespread{1.04}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

\let\oldto\to
\let\oldmapsto\mapsto
\newcommand*{\oldtendsto}{\mathrel{\rightarrow}}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Stealth[scale=1]}}
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=0.4pt}}

\let\oldrightarrow\rightarrow
\newcommand{\newrightarrow}{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline]\draw[arrows=-{Stealth[scale=1]},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (1.4em,0);}}
\newcommand{\newto}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\newrightarrow}{\oldrightarrow}}}
\newcommand{\newbarredrightarrow}{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline]\draw[arrows={Bar[line width=1.125pt,scale=1.667]}-{Stealth[scale=1.44]},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (1.95em,0);}}
\newcommand{\newmapsto}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\newbarredrightarrow}{\oldrightarrow}}}

% command \test based upon the one used by Ruixi Zhang in answer at
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443614/what-length-arrow-for-converges-to/443623#443623
\newcommand*{\test}[3]{% params; tendsto, to, mapsto
  \makebox[7em][r]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}, \texttt{\textbackslash#2} and \texttt{\textbackslash#3}}:\\[6pt]
  Let $(x_n)_{n \in \N} \csname#1\endcsname x$ in~$X$ where $f \from X \csname#2\endcsname Y$ and $x \csname#3\endcsname y$;
  that is, \[\lim_{n \csname#1\endcsname \infty} x_n = x \quad \text{where $\quad f \from X \csname#2\endcsname Y$ and $x \csname#3\endcsname y$}.\]}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\test{oldtendsto}{oldto}{oldmapsto}% original
\test{newto}{newto}{newmapsto}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 & Y \arrow{dr}{g} & \\
X \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{d}{h} & Y \arrow{d}{k}
\\
Z \arrow{r}{g} & W
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: new \to, \mapsto]

**The original query**

I had been looking for the actual definition of the `tikz-cd` the `\mapsto` arrow command (so that I can modify the height and thickness of the bar on its left end).

Thanks to comments from @Phelype Oleinik and @marmot, I did find the definition in `texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`. Unfortunately, with my limited knowledge of `TikZ` I don't find it informative (yet).

Comment: The code for `tikz-cd` is located at `texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`

Comment: Alas, there's no `\Mapsto` defined in that file.

Comment: It is, the definition is `Mapsto/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd implies bar-tikzcd implies}},`. The perhaps simplest way to go is to define a new *style* like `\tikzset{MyMapsto/.style={{Tee Barb[0pt]}-{Stealth[]}}}`.

Comment: Yes, I did find `Mapsto` there; I was mistakenly searching for `\Mapsto` in that file. But the code is not very informative to me, at least not yet.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Now I am confused what the role of `tikz-cd` is in this question (apart from loading `tikz`). According to how I read your question, you are not too happy with how `Mapsto` looks in this library, and you know how to patch arrows with the `arrows.meta` library anyway. So where does `tikz-cd` come in?

Comment: The connectin with `tikz-cd` is simply that I thought by looking at the code there for `mapsto` (and `Mapsto`), it would help me see how to design the version of the`\mapsto` symbol. But it did not.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying this. And, according to what I see, your code already accomplishes what you seemingly want. Apart from the fact that you may want to use `\mathrel` instead of `\mathbin`, as clarified in your [follow-up (?) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443928/are-to-and-mapsto-mathbin-or-mathrel), what is it that you want to achieve. Is it that `\scalerel` makes the line too thin? (Notice that Ti*k*Z understands `width`, i.e. you could simply make the arrow as long as the reference arrow without changing the line width.)

Comment: @marmot: Please explain how to use Ti*k*Z's `width` for the line. Or did you mean `line width`?

Comment: @murray No, I mean `width`. Try e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{width("ABC")}
\typeout{\X}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{height("ABC")}
\typeout{\X}`. Of course the `calc` package (not the `calc` library) also offers `\widthof` and `\heightof`.

Comment: @marmot: I'm confused! Are you talking about the overall width (i.e., thickness) of the lines (i.e., strokes) used to make the shaft of the arrow *and* the bar *and* the bar (if any)? I just do not understand how `width` is to be used where with the `\tikz[baseline]\draw[arrows...` command.

Comment: Most likely it is irrelevant but I simply do not understand the question. So I was *guessing* that you may not like the width of the line of the arrow, and was wondering if you might want to use a different means to rescale your arrow.

Comment: @marmot: I'm trying to change everything about these arrows: increase their overall lengths a bit; increase the thickness of their shafts; make more prominent right-end arrow tips; and for `\mapsto`, a slightly longer and ever-so-thicker bar on the left end. The overall rescaling I'm attempting with `\scalerel*` is to properly scale when the arrows are used in `\scriptstyle`.

Comment: Yes, that's the part I understand. But you are doing that already, don't you? So what are the issues an answer should address?

Answer (score 4):

For the length of the arrows you can use the parameters `row sep` and `column sep` which define the distance between two nodes/cells in your diagram. After here http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf you can see at paragraph 1.3 Changing arrow tips, where there is a list that it shows all available arrow types.

At the page 8 you can modify the thickness of the barb:

```
% in preamble
\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}
}

% in document body
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r, tail] \arrow[rd] & B \arrow[d, two heads] \\
  & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: My error in problem statement (corrected now). I'm actually looking to modify the code for `\Mapsto` so that I can modify it for use in place of the standard LaTeX math symbol `\mapsto`. So I want an arrow with a zero width Tee Barb on its left end and an arrow head (as it happens, a Stealth type tip) on its right end.

Comment: Can you add an image thus I undestand your request?

Comment: What is the reason for the 4th downvote in this day?

Comment: Just upvoted to compensate the downvote, also have no idea why someone would downvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just spelling out the comment and correcting a mistake: the argument of `Tee Barb` needs to be corrected. I actually do not know the reason why the `tikz-cd` library works with `.code` instead of `.style`, so I hope I am not doing something terribly stupid here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{MyMapsto/.style={{Tee Barb[width=0pt]}-{Stealth[]}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
X   \arrow[r,MyMapsto]& Y\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]