# Are `\to` and `\mapsto` mathbin or mathrel?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

What class of symbols are `\to` and `\mapsto`— mathbin or mathrel?

(Sorry for such a basic and naive question!)

I'm pretty sure that usage indicates they ought to be mathrel, but in some posts about redefining `\to`, I've seen mathbin instead.

Comment: @Milo: Yes, I know what the difference is between mathbin and mathrel. So far as I can see, the answer you cite does not answer my question about which of the two classes `\to` and `\mapsto` fall into.

Comment: Note that the "→" in "f(x) → c as x → 0" is a relation, but the "→" in "f : S→T" is a binary operation. Too bad mathematicians used the same right-arrow for both...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\to` and `\mapsto` are defined by the LaTeX kernel.  Their definition can be found in the file `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"21}
   \let\to=\rightarrow
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"37}
   \def\mapsto{\mapstochar\rightarrow}
```

As you can see, `\to` is just a synonym for `\rightarrow`, which is defined as a `\mathrel`.  On the other hand, `\mapsto` is obtained by juxtaposing two relation symbols, `\mapstochar` and `\rightarrow`; it is a low-level feature of TeX that the juxtaposition of two relation symbols acts as a single relation symbol.

Note that there is a command, named `latexdef`, that you can execute from the command line to find out the definition of LaTeX commands (for further details, run

```
latexdef -h
```

always from the command line).  Now, running

```
latexdef \to
```

returns

```
\to:
\mathchar"3221


\the\to:
12833
```

You can see that `\to` is defined to be a symbol of class 3 (you have to look at the first hexadecimal digit of the math code following `\mathchar`), that is, a relation symbol.  Had `\to` been a binary operator, the answer would have been

```
\to:
\mathchar"2221
```

instead.  Similar remarks apply to `\mapstochar`.

Comment: Wow, +1 for `latexdef`! I've been using TeX for years and this is a great new find for me.

Comment: Extremely informative about everything. For example, I knew about `\show` used in interactive mode when one hits an "unknown" error, but not about `latexdef`.

Comment: `\latexdef \mapsto` gives `macro:->\mapstochar \rightarrow`; both `\rightarrow` and `\mapstochar` are of class 3 (mathrel). What rule implies then that `\mapsto` in fact yields a math relation symbol?